# Inject virtual Windows Server 2008 settings/config to physical server

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, virtualization

Is it possible to configure Windows Server 2008 virtually (services, software, policies, folder structure etc) and then inject those configurations and system settings to a physical server with Windows Server 2008?

And can this be done with the built-in backup tools from Win2008?

Comment: Sort of like an inverse p2v?

Comment: Indeed, a v2p..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does sound like Windows backup is what you want.  Make sure you get the system state with the backup.  Then build the physical server, install the O/S and restore.  Best part is you can test it with several virtuals since the O/S is identical.

This [restore reference](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2009/02/04/windows-server-backup-2008-restore-from-network-location.aspx) might help

Comment: Thx for the link!

Answer (score 0):

V2P is possible, however the programs available are expensive, take a look at Novell Platespin Migrate, I've used it before and it migrates the workloads well.